# Difference between CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW vs Createorreplacetempview in spark databricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

In databricks, what's the difference between the two methods.

```
%sql

CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW diamonds
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", 
         header "true")
OK
```

==================================================================

```
dataFrame = "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv"
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true")\
  .option("inferSchema", "true").load(dataFrame)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("diamonds")
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first (SQL version) won't work because views could be created only from other tables or views (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html)), and couldn't be created from files - to create them that you need to either use [CREATE TABLE USING](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html), like this:

```sql
create table test.test using csv 
options ('header' = 'true') 
location 'databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv'
```

and then do `CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW diamonds_view AS SELECT ....`

Or you can wrap it around select from files (although it may not work for all file types, or options may not be supported):

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW diamonds_view AS 
SELECT * FROM csv.`databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv`
```

Everything is really depends on if you're doing processing using only SQL, or not.  If not, the second option will give you the possibility to "export" dataframe as table for data processing.